# Node-red flows state to survive on crashes and restarts

Tags: node-red

I wonder if there is a solution for above, probably persisting flow execution state to db and restore it on start.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to do this, especially as the is no way to know the internal state of every node on the flow